# Making coercions explicit in assumptions in Coq

Tags: coq

I do not really understand how to work with coercions in Coq. Example:

```
Inductive T1:=
   | P1: T1.
Inductive T2:=
   | T1_of: T1 -> T2.
Coercion T1_of: T1 >-> T2.
Variable S: Set.
Variable f: T2 -> Set.
Lemma L: f P1 -> True.
intro.
```

I get the following assumption:

```
H : f P1
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it the case that the "real" type of H is "f (T1_of P1)" and "f P1" is just a nice printing for "f (T1_of P1)"?
2. Is there a way to rewrite this assumption as

```
H : f (T1_of P1)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

[Indeed](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/implicit-coercions.html).

1. Yes, this is just syntactic sugar, the underlying term is the one you mention.
2. Use the [`Set Printing Coercions` command](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/implicit-coercions.html#coq:flag.Printing-Coercions) or the option provided in your IDE.